# Get unique values from a multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, vba, unique

Can anyone give me `VBA` code to help me with the following problem ?

I have this array called `data` with some repeated values in the columns:

**Input**

```
data()= 

  {

       0,0,0,a,b,a,c,b,c,d,0,0

       0,0,0,1,2,1,9,2,9,4,0,0

       0,0,0,r,g,r,w,g,t,w,0,0

}
```

I want to populate an multidimensional `arr` with the information of the non repeated values of the `data` array.

And also: not considering zero values and it does matter which value you will choose from the repeated ones (since the columns are equal)

**Output**

```
arr()=
 {

       a,b,c,d

       1,2,9,4

       r,g,w,w

}
```

Comment: You can remove the zeros easily by copying only nonzero values to the new array. You should look up "how to remove duplicates from an array in VBA".

Comment: Why is `w` duplicated in the output array?  Why not `r`, or `g`?  Or is this like Excel's remove duplicates function but on transposed data (i.e. on columns instead of rows)?

Answer (score 0):

One way to get uniques from one multidimensional array to another
(using 2 dictionaries, the inner gets uniques, and the outer holding them in strings)

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetUniquesFromMultiDimArray()
    Dim arrData As Variant, arrUniques As Variant, itm As Variant

    arrData = Array(Split("0,0,0,a,b,a,c,b,c,d,0,0", ","), _
                    Split("0,0,0,1,2,1,9,2,9,4,0,0", ","), _
                    Split("0,0,0,r,g,r,w,g,t,w,0,0", ","))
    ShowArray arrData, 1

    Dim d1 As Object, d2 As Object, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    k = 1
    'each item in d1 holds a string of uniques
    Set d1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)

        'each item in d2 holds non-zero uniques
        Set d2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

        For j = LBound(arrData(i)) To UBound(arrData(i))
            If arrData(i)(j) <> 0 Then d2(arrData(i)(j)) = vbNullString
        Next
        For Each itm In d2
            d1(k) = d1(k) & itm & ","           'example: "1,2,9,4,"
        Next
        d1(k) = Left(d1(k), Len(d1(k)) - 1)     'example: "1,2,9,4"
        k = k + 1
    Next
    ReDim arrUniques(1 To d1.Count)
    For i = 1 To d1.Count
        arrUniques(i) = Split(d1(i), ",")       'example: Array("1","2","9","4")
    Next
    ShowArray arrUniques, 2
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub ShowArray(ByRef arr As Variant, ByVal arrId As Long)
    Dim itm1 As Variant, itm2 As Variant, i As Long, j As Long

    Debug.Print "Start array " & arrId & " --------"
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        For j = LBound(arr(i)) To UBound(arr(i))
            Debug.Print "arr(" & i & ")(" & j & ") = " & arr(i)(j)
        Next
    Next
    Debug.Print "End array   " & arrId & " --------" & vbCrLf
End Sub
```

---

Output:

```
Start array 1 --------
arr(0)(0) = 0
arr(0)(1) = 0
arr(0)(2) = 0
arr(0)(3) = a
arr(0)(4) = b
arr(0)(5) = a
arr(0)(6) = c
arr(0)(7) = b
arr(0)(8) = c
arr(0)(9) = d
arr(0)(10) = 0
arr(0)(11) = 0

arr(1)(0) = 0
arr(1)(1) = 0
arr(1)(2) = 0
arr(1)(3) = 1
arr(1)(4) = 2
arr(1)(5) = 1
arr(1)(6) = 9
arr(1)(7) = 2
arr(1)(8) = 9
arr(1)(9) = 4
arr(1)(10) = 0
arr(1)(11) = 0

arr(2)(0) = 0
arr(2)(1) = 0
arr(2)(2) = 0
arr(2)(3) = r
arr(2)(4) = g
arr(2)(5) = r
arr(2)(6) = w
arr(2)(7) = g
arr(2)(8) = t
arr(2)(9) = w
arr(2)(10) = 0
arr(2)(11) = 0
End array   1 --------
```

> ```
> Start array 2 --------
> arr(1)(0) = a
> arr(1)(1) = b
> arr(1)(2) = c
> arr(1)(3) = d
>
> arr(2)(0) = 1
> arr(2)(1) = 2
> arr(2)(2) = 9
> arr(2)(3) = 4
>
> arr(3)(0) = r
> arr(3)(1) = g
> arr(3)(2) = w
> arr(3)(3) = t
> End array   2 --------
> ```

---

(assuming the duplicate `w` in your output is a mistake, as mentioned in the comment)